# How to avoid destroying backbone view unnecessarily?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a view in which two tabs are shown.

Tab visibility is controlled simply by css class. Here is the code:

```
class PlansView extends Backbone.View
  className: 'plans-view tab1-selected'

  events:
    'click .btn-buy': 'buyItems' 
    'click .tab1': 'switchToTab1'
    'click .tab2': 'switchToTab2'

  switchToTab1: (event) =>
    this.$el.toggleClass 'tab1-selected', no
    this.$el.toggleClass 'tab2-selected', yes
    window.location.hash = 'tab1'

  switchToTab2: (event) =>
    this.$el.toggleClass 'tab1-selected', yes
    this.$el.toggleClass 'tab2-selected', no
    window.location.hash = 'tab2'
```

I use the `window.location.hash` in the functions because when the tab switches, I want the url to reflect this. i.e. When the url is `mycompany.com/view#tab1`, tab 1 is activated. If it is `mycompany.com/view#tab2`, i want to show the tab 2.

However what happened is that: when the hash is changed, the router is triggered! The view is then unloaded and then loaded again. It shows a very clear visual jerking.

It is the relevant code in the router:

```
_showSection: (event) ->
  sectionView = new PlansView event

  @previousView?.remove()

  @previousView = sectionView
  @$sectionHolder.append sectionView.el
```

If I remove the `window.location.hash` statements, the tab switches very smoothly but the url will stay unchange.

For some reason the pushState is disabled in the project. I don't think I can change this for now.

```
new Router()
Backbone.history.start pushState: false
```

Is there anyway I can update the hash without triggering the router code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Backbone.history.navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) instead of `window.location.hash`.

```
Backbone.history.navigate '#tab1'
```

The reason the router is triggered is because Backbone listens to hash changes and triggers route accordingly.

The default behavior of the `navigate` function is only to change the hash, and if you want to trigger the route, you need to explicitly set the `trigger: true` option.